# Pandas Column Transformation with list of dict in column

Tags: pandas

I am getting the data from a nosql database own by third party. Post data fetch the dataframe look like below: I wish to explode perfomance column but can't figure out a way. Is it even possible?

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['name', 'performance']
data = [
    ['bob',   [{'dates': '15-12-2021', 'gdp': 19},
 {'dates': '16-12-2021', 'gdp': 36},
 {'dates': '12-12-2022', 'gdp': 39},
 {'dates': '13-12-2022', 'gdp': 35},
 {'dates': '14-12-2022', 'gdp': 35}]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Expected output:

```
cols = ['name', 'dates', 'gdp']

data = [
    ['bob',   '15-12-2021', 19],
    ['bob',   '16-12-2021', 36],
    ['bob',   '12-12-2022', 39],
    ['bob',   '13-12-2022', 35],
    ['bob',  '14-12-2022', 35]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first and then flatten dictionaries by [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for remove column `performance` in ouput `DataFrame`:

```
df1  = df.explode('performance').reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = df1.join(pd.json_normalize(df1.pop('performance')))
print (df1)
  name       dates  gdp
0  bob  15-12-2021   19
1  bob  16-12-2021   36
2  bob  12-12-2022   39
3  bob  13-12-2022   35
4  bob  14-12-2022   35
```

Another solutions with list comprehension - if  only 2 columns input DataFrame:

```
L = [{**{'name':a},**x}  for a, b in zip(df['name'], df['performance']) for x in b]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df1)
  name       dates  gdp
0  bob  15-12-2021   19
1  bob  16-12-2021   36
2  bob  12-12-2022   39
3  bob  13-12-2022   35
4  bob  14-12-2022   35
```

If multiple columns use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with original `DataFrame`:

```
L = [{**{'i':a},**x}  for a, b in df.pop('performance').items() for x in b]

df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L).set_index('i')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
  name       dates  gdp
0  bob  15-12-2021   19
1  bob  16-12-2021   36
2  bob  12-12-2022   39
3  bob  13-12-2022   35
4  bob  14-12-2022   35
```